# Run Flutter Integration Tests in Parallel

Tags: flutter, parallel-testing, flutter-integration-test

I plan to run the flutter integration tests across different iOS/Android Simulators/Emulators in parallel.

As per [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/integration-tests#running-using-the-flutter-command), we can run the flutter integration tests across the device using:

```
flutter test integration_test/foo_test.dart -d <DEVICE_ID>
```

My concern is:

1. Is there a way to build the flutter binaries only like: `xcodebuild build-for-testing`
2. Is there way to split the integration tests across multiple simulators in parallel?